# Bootstrap css: change few div to rtl

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, right-to-left

i have below fiddle link currently as it is rtl, but i want few div (English Language) as ltr, any help would be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/jZm8D/1/'>

Comment: in this page i want to change bootstrap panel group to ltr

Comment: What exactly is your question? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a class that makes text ltr and add it to div elements that contains English language.

```css
.ltr {
        direction: ltr !important;
    }
```